# Как лучше всего хранить большую таблицу?

Tags: база-данных, mariadb, sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача хранить большую таблицу с данными - где-то 10-20 столбцов и несколько сотен тысяч записей. Из операций - периодическое обновление(добавление новых записей) и поиск по некоторым полям. Как лучше всего организовать хранение?
Сам склоняюсь к MariaDB с одной большой таблицей в БД, но, может, есть лучшие способы?

Comment: Redis можно посмотреть

Comment: разве это большая таблица? Хотя конечно нужно смотреть, какие у Вас запросы по скорости. Но думаю, MariaDB справится (главное, индексы правильно добавить). Для начала напишите класс-обертку над базой, что бы все работало только через нее. В будущем сможете подменить  базу и посмотреть, как оно будет работать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несколько сотен тысяч записей - это маленькая таблица. С этой задачей справится любая СУБД. Вот когда размер таблицы будет исчисляться гигабайтами, вот тогда стоит задуматься.

Answer (score 1):

сомневаюсь что одна большая таблица находится хотя бы в первой нормальной форме.
был у меня случай когда один добрый разработчик запихнул в 1 таблицу реляционной бд даже не иерархическую а сетевую структуру, где поля меняли своё значение. затем пришли другие разработчики и наделали хранимых процедур где эта табличка сама с собой по 20 раз джойнилась (типа поиск объекта и его параметров). все это работало ужасно медленно.
закончилось тем что из 1й "большой" пришлось сделать 50 обычных..